# Laravel filter by many to many relation of a relation

Tags: laravel, filter, many-to-many, relationship, relation

I'm writing a movie and serie database. I want to make it possible to filter by genre.

For the movie part it's quite easy. In my movie model I just could add a genre scope:

```
public function scopeGenres($query, $genres)
{
    return $query->whereHas('genres', function($q) use ($genres){
        $q->whereIn('genres.genre_id', $genres);
    });
}
```

Now I want to include it with the series model. The problem: I display the seasons and not the series and the genres are attached to the series.

It's like:

```
Season belongsTo Serie morphToMany Genre
```

I already tried to make it like:

```
$seasons->with('serie' => function($query) use ($genre_ids){
    $query->whereHas('genres', function($q) use ($genre_ids){  
        $q->whereIn('genres.genre_id', $genres);
    });
});
```

but with no success.

How can I filter the season by Genre?

Comment: What's no success mean exactly?  No results? Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to replace `with` function with another `whereHas`

```
$seasons->whereHas('serie', function($query) use ($genre_ids) { 
    $query->whereHas('genres', function($q) use ($genre_ids){ 
        $q->whereIn('genres.genre_id', $genres);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Damned so easy.... Works perfect! I wouldn't have come up with that idea. Thanks!